# OpenGL window from one application in another

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, opengl

I have one application using C++ + SDL2 + OpenGL, I want to create second application in c#/wpf that have embedded window from first application, is it possible ? If yes, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

When I went down this route, I started [at this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265903/Using-OpenGL-in-a-WPF-Application)

In a nutshell, I used the [SharpGL](http://sharpgl.codeplex.com/) library to initialize the GL context and then told my application (housed completely in an unmanaged dll) 'use the current context instead of creating a new one'.

I wasnt using SDL, but I imagine you will have to translate the user input events from WPF into something that 'looks like' SDL events. For me, I was converting key and mouse events into GLUT keycodes so that I didnt have to have two sets of key handling logic.